# Grub Customizer will not install on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2

I am trying to install Grub Customizer to customize Grub menus, without success.

[image: repos and PPAs enabled]

[image: error while installing from Software Center]

The following instructions (which can be found on various websites) are meant to install `grub-customizer` if typed into the Terminal and make it show up in the application list:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

After running these instructions, `grub-customizer` is nowhere to be found (especially not in the application list).

It lists the link of the program in the software section of settings with a check mark on the program link, which confuses me.

I tried with no success:

- mostly the same instruction from several different sites.
- going to the direct site where it was located, downloading a version of it, and it downloaded, but it didn't show up in the application list.
- I figured that it was in the downloads list, so I clicked on it, and it pulled up the Ubuntu software program which gave me an error "dependency is not satisfiable" followed by a few random characters.

I gave up trying after that.

Comment: can you be more specific about "it lists the link of the program" ? where does it do this ? Did you spot any error written in the terminal after running each of the instructions ? have you tried ``sudo apt-get install -f``. Your question lacks a lot of specific details. What happens if you try ``which grub-customizer`` ? The "random characters" might be quite important here.

Answer (score 0):

The images of the error in the ubuntu software center and the software settings app have been linked. This problem was resolved by typing in sudo apt-get -f install; sudo apt-get install grub-customizer; lsb_release -a; uname -a to the terminal, it then downloaded Grubb Customizer.